# Sorting ArrayList based on certain attributes

Tags: java, jsp

i am in process to show the data on the UI as per the HTML provided by the client and i got struck in a way here.
This is how i need to show the data on UI

1. style
2. swatchColour
3. size1
4. siz2

i am getting data in following order

1. style
2. size2
3. swatchColour
4. size1

May be data can come in other ordering but i need to show data in the manner shown in first block,i can not change the way data is being returned as that API is not under my control, so i left with one choice to sort the data based on my priority list and send it to UI so i can display it.

using the following code

```
Collections.sort(string,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

it sorting data in following order

1. style
2. swatchColour
3. size2
4. size1

so its doing the way it should have done like size2 is coming before size1.i am not sure what type of comparator i should write or should i check this size1 and size2 string in my custom comparator and leave rest of the data the way it is being sorted?
or is there any way like to create my sorting list so as i can use that to sort the List

**Eidt**

I am more interested the way to sort size1 and size2 like String in human way like size1 should size2 should come later.

any suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: What you need is [`Collections.sort(List data, Comparator comp)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E)) method.

Comment: @AleksG:i am agree with that, but how you will compare those 2 string with number? do we need to check them with specific name or ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are these data coming in separately for each item/product, and you just want to know how to sort different values for the size variables? Or are you trying to sort a list of product/item objects by taking into account all of these variables?

Answer (score 1):

just create your own comparator and set your own custom rules there.

java can't have all of the possible rules for comparing strings , since there are infinite number of them.

Comment: my question is more towards how to do that? do i need to create my list of words or is there a way i can sort those string in human way like `size1` should be before `size2`

Comment: no, you should figure out what are the rules (algorithm) that you wish to compare . in order to do it , go over the characters of each of the strings and decide when to return -1/0/1 according to which of them is considered "larger" . here's an example of using comparator for integer : http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/ . a similar thing can be done for strings.